# How do I proceed after B1 visa denial under section 214(b)?

Tags: usa, indian-citizens, visa-refusals, b1-b2-visas

I'm a final year student, I have written my final exams & am waiting for the results. I have won an Apple WWDC Scholarship this year to attend the conference June 5-9 in San Jose, California. However, my visa was denied under INA section 214(b). I'm thinking of re-applying with following to prove that I intend to my home country, India.

1. I want to be an entrepreneur and am not interested in employment. As evidence, I have built a couple of products and making money from them. Also, I'm a bug bounty hunter and have earned more than $4000 so far from various Internet companies. I'll be returning to my country to start my own business
2. My parents have a financially stable jobs in India and own property here. Also, all my family members live in India.
3. I would accept a visa with validity for only a month or even less.

Comment: What's your nationality?

Comment: None of those reasons seem particularly compelling to me, unfortunately.

Comment: Damn, that seems harsh. Didn't you have a face to face interview with the interviewing officer where you got a chance to point these facts?

Answer (score 4):

> How do I proceed after B1 visa denial under section 214(b)?

You can reapply **immediately**, however because there is no change in your circumstances the chances are slim and none. The three reasons you plan to articulate for reconsideration are nothing special, they don't move the needle.

A scholarship from Apple is prestigious and would have bolstered your credentials, however the timing of having essentially graduated school works heavily against you. You're in reality a young person at this point with the proverbial world at your feet and unfettered to move anywhere you want.My assertion is based on personal experience as well as from people I know over the years.

Normally I would say do not reapply immediately however in your case, you have little to lose except $160. If you are refused and in future you plan to come to the USA for school, two refusals for B1/B2 would probably not affect your application much nor would it affect an H1B employment type application. Any future B1/B2 application after two successive refusals would however be problematic if your circumstances have not changed significantly in the interim.

Roll the dice. American visa interviews are typically very short and you would want to put out there fairly quickly why you deserve reconsideration. The Apple name/scholarship might sway the interviewer plus WWDC is a big deal.

I don't think you should include point #3.

> I would accept a visa with validity for only a month or even less.

After all an absconder only needs two minutes on US soil to go underground.